# Always show vertical scrollbar in <select>

Tags: html, css

The following code produces a listbox with 2 options:

```
<select size="10">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to always show a vertical scrollbar in this listbox?
I'm asking this question because style="overflow-y: scroll;" doesn't work here in IE7.

Comment: overflow-y:scroll is correct but with that add width also in the style

Comment: overflow-y:scroll doesn't work for select

Comment: Of course it won't work if no height is set... (plus, I think IE doesn't know about `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` seperately, it's all down to `overflow`)

Comment: IE recognizes 'overflow-x' and 'overflow-y' styles in DIV.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will work in IE7. But here you need to fixed the `size` less than the number of `option` and not use `overflow-y:scroll`. In your example you have 2 `option` but you set `size=10`, which will not work.

Suppose your select has 10 `option`, then fixed `size=9`.

Here, in your code reference you used `height:100px` with `size:2`. I remove the `height` css, because its not necessary and change the `size:5` and it works fine.

Here is your modified code from jsfiddle:

```
<select size="5" style="width:100px;">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 <option>6</option>
</select>
```

this will generate a larger select box than `size:2` create.In case of small `size` the select box will not display the scrollbar,you have to check with appropriate `size` quantity.Without scrollbar it will work if click on the upper and lower icons of scrollbar.I show both example in your fiddle with `size:2` and `size` greater than `2`(e.g: 3,5).

***Here is your desired result. I think this will help you:***

**CSS**

```
  .wrapper{
    border: 1px dashed red;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 150px;
 }
 .wrapper .selection{
   width:150px;
   border:1px solid #ccc
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<select size="15" class="selection">
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I created an example on http://jsfiddle.net/MVf55/1/. You can open it in Firefox and then in IE. Internet Explorer doesn't show the scroll here. Could you correct my code?

Comment: HI, mate: Sorry for late response. I was offline for some reason.I make some changes in your code and it works well.Please check this.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to reduce the height of select. I want to show a scroll even in select which does not contain any options.

Comment: @Egor4eg Hi friend, I give my solution and think at last I may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cant, this maybe a limitation or not included in the IE browser. I have tried your jsfiddle with IE6-8 and all of it doesn't show the scrollbar and not sure with IE9. While in FF and chrome the scrollbar is shown. I also want to see how to do it in IE if possible.

If you really want to show the scrollbar, you can add a fake scrollbar. If you are familiar with some of the js library which use in RIA. Like in [jquery](http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/254/)/[dojo](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-0.4.3/dojo-0.4.3-widget/tests/widget/test_Select.html) some of the select is editable, because it is a combination of textbox + select or it can also be a textbox + div.

As an example, see it [here](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html) a JavaScript that make select like editable.

Answer (score -4):

add:

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

in your css bud.