# Scrollbars for Select

Tags: html, scrollbars

I am working on a cell with a select element and supposedly would have scrollbars (horizontal and vertical) appearing if needed.

I have this code:

```
 <div style="border:solid; border-width:1px; overflow:auto ; width:135px; 
  height:40px" align="left">
<select name="selSubscriberList" style="border:none; min-width:145px; height: 30px;" </select>
```

My porblem here is, aside from the vertical scrollbar that the div generates, the input select also has
its vertical scroll. So when I slide the horizontal scroll to far right, the vertical scroll of select shows.

How do I get around on this. Quite frustrating. :(

thank,
tinks

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve... anyway you have a typo in your code (the select tag is not closed). When I run this code I don't get any vertical scrollbar on the select, only the drop-down opening button. What browser are you using?

Comment: I actually just want to have a vertical and horizontal scrollbar for my select..an i am using IE8.. the scrollbars show up actually except that since they are scrollbars of the div, then my select has more elements than the set size, if shows its own vertical scrollbar, thus making redundant.

Comment: I wish I can upload image for clearer "explanation". This my first time for web dev and it is really frustrating >.<

Comment: Yeah, an image would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to control the behavior of your elements (div, select) if an overflow occurs (that means the content is bigger than the element itself). Try this:

```
<div style="overflow: visible; border: solid; border-width:1px; width:135px; height:40px" align="left">
    <select name="selSubscriberList" style="overflow: auto; border:none; min-width:145px; height: 30px;">
```

Comment: hi thanks, but i think it didnt work.. I found this and tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715705/always-show-vertical-scrollbar-in-select, the vertical scrollbar was working great but when i set overflow-x:scroll, that's when my problem occurs if both height and width are greater than the set sizes..the vertical scrollbar of the div and the select are showing, giving me 2 vertical scrollbars, if i allow overflow-x:scroll..

Comment: do you think I can show the horizontal scroll and one vertical scroll?