# Add scrollbar on dropdown menu options

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, scroll

I am trying to add a scrollbar to a dropdown menu options so when user clicks the menu it won't show all the options all the way till end. I tried

```
<select name='menu'>
  <option value='1'>first item</option>
  <option value='2'>second item</option>
  <option value='3'>third item</option>
  <option value='4'>fourth item</option>
  <option value='5'>fifth item</option>
  <option>........
  <option>........
  //I have many options.....
</select>
```

I try this css but it only works on the menu itself, not options.

```
select {
height:50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think this is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715705/always-show-vertical-scrollbar-in-select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is also I nice way of handeling it :)

http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/

From the link above:

```
var maxHeight = 400; $(function(){

$(".dropdown > li").hover(function() {

     var $container = $(this),
         $list = $container.find("ul"),
         $anchor = $container.find("a"),
         height = $list.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
         multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller

    // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
    $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

    // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
    $anchor.addClass("hover");

    // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
    $list
        .show()
        .css({
            paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
        });

    // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
    if (multiplier > 1) {
        $container
            .css({
                height: maxHeight,
                overflow: "hidden"
            })
            .mousemove(function(e) {
                var offset = $container.offset();
                var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                    $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                };
            });
    }

}, function() {

    var $el = $(this);

    // put things back to normal
    $el
        .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
        .find("ul")
        .css({ top: 0 })
        .hide()
        .end()
        .find("a")
        .removeClass("hover");

});

// Add down arrow only to menu items with submenus
$(".dropdown > li:has('ul')").each(function() {
    $(this).find("a:first").append("<img src='images/down-arrow.png' />");
});
```

});

Comment: The scroll speed is very fast, how to control it

Comment: @Tarun I suggest you create a new question for that. Create a js fiddle (jsfiddle.net) as well and I'm sure yo'll get a good answer in no time!

Comment: When I am trying `http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/`. The drop down has some problem with below DOM elements. The z-index is not affecting. The drop down is hitting on the below items. Can you tell me any solution.

Answer (score 21):

give a css to your select like `class="myDropDown"` and add the following css

```
.myDropDown
{
   height: 50px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

for reference: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANn2N/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
          /*dropdown menu code start*/
          @media only screen and (min-width:769px) {
              .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
                  display: block;
              }
              .dropdown-submenu {
                  position: relative !important;
              }

              .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
                  top: 0 !important;
                  left: 100% !important;
                  margin-top: -6px !important;
                  margin-left: -1px !important;
                  border-radius: 0 !important;
              }

              .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
                  display: block !important;
              }

              .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
                  display: block;
                  content: "\f105";
                  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
                  margin-top: -18px;
                  right: 15px;
                  position: absolute;
                  font-weight: 300;
              }
              .customcaret{
                float: right;
              }
            }
          /*dropdown menu code start*/

         .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
            color: #535353;
            transition: all ease 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
            font-size: 1.15em !important;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        </style>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it is ok, on what your solution is based, etc ?

Comment: Please explain briefly what does this code do. Code only answers are not very helpful.