# How to make scroll bars Always show up in my drop-downs for all browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser

I have a scroll bar inside a dropdown and I want it shows up all the time like this:
[image]

However, this only works in some old version safari and firefox. And in my new safari/chrome, there is no scroll bar at all.

[image]

How can I fix that so I can make sure for most browsers, the scroll bar will be there all the time?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: These answers should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624578/add-scrollbar-on-dropdown-menu-options

Comment: @rob_towner Sorry but this is the way i'm using :-( Not works for new browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there was a change of behaviour post Mountain Lion where scroll bars are hidden by default. Try this snippet; I've used it to force scroll bars to display.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  width: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply! This works but the thing is, the scroll bar disappears after 2 seconds :-)

Comment: @jackhao Try adding the last bit. I just updated my answer. Not sure if that will help, though.

Comment: Hey it works actually. Thanks so much. But the thing is my whole page scroll bar shows up all the time as well. Is there a way I only do this for my dropdowns?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes: Try applying those styles only to specific classes.

Comment: Thanks but I tried something like this: ::-webkit-scrollbar #primary{....} bu it's not working. How should I add classes/ids to it..? Thx!

Comment: Did you try something like `.some_class ::-webkit-scrollbar` ? Also if you are using SASS you can nest it: .some_class { ::-webkit ...`

Comment: Yeah it's not working as well if I move it to the beginning :-( I guess I have to use it for the whole page.