# how to show scroll bar for a select box with size 2 in IE browsers

Tags: html, css

I need to implement a select box with only two options.
it works fine with size=2 and height=34px in Firefox but 
in IE it does not show scrollbar.

```
<select size="2" style="height:34px;">
  <option value="1">Enabled</option>
  <option value="2">Disabled</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: create a fiddle for the same please!

Comment: Why do you need a scroll bar if both options are visible?

Comment: i need scrollbar for similarity in all browser..

Comment: You already have _similarity_ in all browsers, what you don't have is _identicalness_. In my opinion you don't _need_ the latter, and if anything I think IE is more correct in not displaying an unnecessary scrollbar. But to answer your question, have a look at the second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5717466/615754) (yes, it's a hack).