# How to show vertical scroll bar on select box

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, css

I am using angular select box ,i need to show a scroll bar if data is more than 5 .

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model='projectListData.appVersion' ng-selected ng-options="v.version as v.version for v in versionList | orderBy:'-version' " >
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose Version</option>
</select>
```

I tried with size but that is not working .

```
size = '5'
```

Please suggest

Comment: Your answer is given here
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715705/always-show-vertical-scrollbar-in-select

Comment: @AR_Web: You've almost got the link sorted. using the `[some text]` followed by the link in brackets `()`. It will end up `[some text](http://)`

Comment: Try using a plugin, If you are looking for dropdown in select it is a browser rendered element and not much controls on scripts. select2 is a plugin look it up

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="versions" class="form-control" data-ng-model='projectListData.appVersion' ng-selected ng-options="v.version as v.version for v in versionList | orderBy:'-version' " >
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose Version</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
if($scope.versionList.length > 5){
    //vanilla js with dropdown defined
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("versions");
    dropdown.style.overflow = "scroll";
    //single line
    document.getElementById("versions").style.overflow = "scroll";
    //JQuery
    $("#versions").css("overflow", "scroll");
}
```